# Show that $\mathbf R$ is Cauchy complete without using least upper bound property, monotone convergence theorem, etc.

Tags: real-analysis

From wiki, $\mathbf R$ has the following properties:

1. Least upper bound property
2. Nested intervals theorem
3. Monotone convergence theorem
4. Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem
5. Cauchy completeness

Moreover, for a general ordered field, (1)-(4) are equivalent, while (5) is weaker than them. However, the proofs of (5) that I have seen all rely on (1)-(4). Can you give a proof of (5) that does not rely on (1)-(4)?

Comment: How do you define the real numbers?

Comment: It kind of depends on how you're defining $\Bbb{R}$, right?  If you define $\Bbb{R}$ as the completion of $\Bbb{Q}$ with respect to the usual Archimedean absolute value, completeness is essentially free.

Comment: No.  Because without 1-4 $\mathbb R$ has no meaning.    The reason we have $\mathbb R$  and are able to refer to it is because we prove an extension of $\mathbb Q$ exists that has 1-4.  We call it $\mathbb R$.  It's a bit like proving kangaroos are marsupials without being allowyed to use any definitions of "placenta" or marsupials lack thereof.

Comment: Any paper treating the definition of $\mathbb{R}$ will prove the least upper bound property. If you want a definition that gives Cauchy completeness easily, the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ via Cauchy-sequences is probably the quickest, even though it is a little bit subtle.

Answer (score 3):

5) is weaker than the others in the sense that 5) should be replaced by 
5)$^\prime$ Cauchy completeness and the Archimedean property.
This means that to prove completeness you do need to use one of the properties 1)-4), while to prove any of the properties 1)-4) you also need the Archimedean property and not just completeness.
For a complete non Archimedean field see [complete-non-archimedean](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17687/example-of-a-complete-non-archimedean-ordered-field)